# #1064 Error in PHPMyAdmin : unwantedORDER BY breaks request

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

There seems to be a major issue with my PHPMyAdmin 4.1.14 running on PHP 5.5.12.

After doing some requests on a table, I cannot display the content of the table anymore and I cannot write a simple SQL request to display it either.

This affects a specific table, other ones run perfect.

So I write :

```
SELECT * FROM pj_empathie WHERE 1
```

I get an error saying that I have tried this request :

```
SELECT * FROM pj_empathie WHERE 1 ORDER BY id desc) ANDaccepte=1 ANDsecret=0 
 LIMIT 0, 25
```

Where does this 'ORDER BY id desc) ANDaccepte=1 ANDsecret=0' comes from ?

I assumed there was some sort of cache somewhere so I tried :

```
CHECK TABLE `pj_empathie`;

ANALYZE TABLE `pj_empathie`; 

REPAIR TABLE `pj_empathie`; 

OPTIMIZE TABLE `pj_empathie`; 

FLUSH TABLE `pj_empathie`;
```

Nothing changed.

Even stranger, if I rename or duplicate the table, the new table works fine. If I rename the database, the table in the new database works fine. But as soon as I try to rename it to the first database name or the first table name, I get the error again.

Thanks for reading :)

EDIT : I have found a way to resolve and reproduce.

First I write this request :

```
SELECT * FROM `pj_empathie` WHERE pj1 IN (SELECT id FROM pj WHERE clan=5 AND clan_accepte = 1 ORDER BY id ASC)
```

This works.

After I have written this request, a simple :

```
SELECT * FROM `pj_empathie` WHERE 1
```

... is not working anymore. PHPMyAdmin tries to automatically add stuff at the end of the request :

```
SELECT * FROM `pj_empathie` WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC)
```

Which looks like a lot the end of the previous one.

But I can write

```
SELECT * FROM `pj_empathie` WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC
```

... and this works, and makes the simple request without the ORDER BY work again after that.

Comment: Seems like you should just delete this question and file a bug report with PMA.

Comment: phpMyAdmin 4.1 is rather outdated, can you reproduce it with a more recent version? You said this only affects one specific table; if you copy the table structure to another database for testing, do you have the same problem? Can you reproduce with the same structure on the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?